# How to call NavigationService from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This is more complex than it sounds. I'm implementing **MVVM pattern**, which states a `ViewModel` **cannot** have a reference to it's `View`. That being said, I'm implementing `Page` navigation so that changes in views are done by using `NavigationService` in the `View`'s code behind (let's say by pressing the "Next" button).

At some point in the program, we need to change `Page` using a voice command instead of a button (using speech recognition), and that logic is handled in the `ViewModel` (which doesn't have a reference to `NavigationService`).

So, without keeping a reference to thew `View` inside the `ViewModel`, how can I change page using `NavigationService`?

Comment: Any reason why not passing the Navigation Service via constructor (using only the Interface in your ViewModel) as @Derek Beattie suggested? Unless your NavigationService uses concrete View types to resolve (i.e. `navigationService.Navigate<MainPage>();') passing the an INavigationService isn't violation of MVVM and doesn't couple your ViewModel with the View

Answer (score 1):

You could publish a "next page requested" message from within your view model using something like an event aggregator. Your view then subscribes to the message and handles it by using NavigationService to change the page. If you are using an MVVM framework most of them provide a way to publish / subscribe to messages out of the box.

Comment: can you provide an example or a guide, I'm new at WPF so I might need some guidance

Comment: Caliburn.Micro event aggregator, for example:
[link](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/event-aggregator)

Answer (score 0):

In your Core (nonUI) project that containts your view models.  Create a `INavigationService` interface:

```
public interface INavigation
{
     void Navigate(IViewModel viewmodel);
     void GoBack();
}
```

Then in your UI project, provide the implementation for that interface.  You can get fancy with how you provide that implementation to the view model.

In the simple form you'd want to do something like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     public MyViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
     {
          _navigationService = navigationService;
     }
}
```

When the app starts up give the view model the implementation.  At that point all your navigation can live in the view model.  If you need to navigate from a view, execute a command on the view model and have it navigate.

Take a look at how MvvmLight does it:
[INavigationService](http://goo.gl/XllFID), 
[NavigationService](http://goo.gl/vAZicD)